# How do I put my header above my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS.

I'm trying to achieve:

[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

I made:

[image: What I made]

I also want the header to be the size of the browser window and it has to be fixed and the navigation bar to be sticky. This is what I have so far. I only watched a few YouTube tutorials to make the navigation bar, but it won't settle below the header.

```css
    /*margin of whole document*/
* {
    margin: 0px;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*font for the whole body */
* {
  font-family: 'Candara', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

/* Set the height of the div to the entire screen */
body {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #98c9cd 3%, #e6c3c1 60%, #e4989e 100%);
    margin: 0;
}

/*for header*/
.topheader {
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

/*for navbar*/
.container{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear: both;
}

header {
     background:rgba(255,255,255,0);
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    transition:background 0.5s ease;
}

header::after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/*for logo in navbar*/
.logo {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

nav {
    float: right;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 70px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul > li > a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
}

nav a:hover {
  color:  #000;
}

nav a::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 0%;
}

nav a:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
    transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}
```

```html
<html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<title>IA2</title>
<header>
    <p id="topheader" style="background-color: #AEBC77;">For announcement posts</h1>
</header>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <img src="finallogo.png" alt="logo" class="logo" width="8%" height="16%">
    <nav>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can all be achieved using flexbox. Create a flexbox with `flex-direction: column` containing the header and the navigation bar. Then inside the navigation bar, you can create another flex box with `flex-direction: row` to display the elements horizontally.
Try reading this -
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

For your current code, try changing the width of the header to `width: 100vw` to make it fit across the entire width of the screen.